# Check availability of a date with one SQL Statement (with overlapping and in between)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: room and availability. In availability there are several blocked dates for each room.

I just want to show available rooms in a given range. My SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM rooms
WHERE av_id NOT IN (
SELECT av_id 
FROM availability 
WHERE (? BETWEEN datetime_start AND datetime_end
    OR ? BETWEEN datetime_start AND datetime_end)
)
```

? and ? is the given date for start and and in my prepared statement.

The problem: This catches just the case if start or end is between dates and not overlapping cases. I read now for an hour other posts but didn't get the right logical approach. I think I have to add another clause with > and <, but don't know exactly how.

Thank you for any hints for a beginner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists` . . . and comparison logic to get any overlap.  I think that is:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM rooms r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM availability a
                  WHERE a.av_id = r.av_id AND
                        :start_dt < a.datetime_end AND
                        :end_dt > a.dt_start
                 );
```

I am surprised that something called `av_id` would be used to link the two tables.  I would expect something called `room_id`.

Comment: Thank you so much!